# PHP push_array objects showing same value

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to get the year month from 2018-01-06 to till day using the php datetime object using the code

```
function getMonths(){
    $st_date = new DateTime('2019-01-01');
    $yms = array($st_date);
    while($st_date < new DateTime()){
        array_push($yms, $st_date->add(new DateInterval('P1M')));
    }
    print_r($yms);
}
```

But the ouput is showing the same values on all the items in the array $yms

```
Array
(
[0] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2019-03-01 00:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
    )

[1] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2019-03-01 00:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
    )
....

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push into an array references to the same object. As a result all items show the same time. Use clone to make new one based on a source object data

```
 function getMonths(){
    $st_date = new DateTime('2019-01-01');
    $yms = array(clone $st_date);
    while($st_date < new DateTime()){
        array_push($yms, clone $st_date->add(new DateInterval('P1M')));
    }
    print_r($yms);
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/455c64b920bbad87949f6aa828b01c08815bd759)

[**Object Cloning**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)